# more than 1 main() methods in a software. Is this due to Maven plug-in?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven, methods, program-entry-point

I am in a company and I hv seen source code of one of its software.
I found more than 25 occurrences of main() method in that.
I analysed some features of myeclipse and found one solution that this is due to maven that is installed in eclipse, which allows u to prepare more than 1 build files for a software.

I want to know, is my analysis true?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

No, your analysis is not true. Any class may have a main method. Just add the method to the class, and it'll be there. The fact the Maven, Eclipse, or MyEclipse is used is irrelevant. Developers have chosen to add a main method in all thoses classes, that's all.

There are pretty good reasons to have several main classes in a jar. For example, if the jar contains a collection of utilities.